# Difficulty converting string to JSON object in order to urlencode it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having some trouble converting a string that I built up over my script into a JSON object (I'm trying to build up post data to make a post request to the API endpoint).

I'm getting the following error:

```
bos-mpqpu:config_parse rabdelaz$ python3 lexparse.py
{"__class__":"HttpTestClient","description":"CP Codes","url":"://","serverip":"","method":"GET","enabled":true,"headers":[],"tests":[],"purge":false,"procs":[]}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lexparse.py", line 448, in <module>
print(ast.literal_eval(test_case_ACT_template.substitute({'protocol': "",'host': "", 'path' : "", 'query' : "", 'serverip' : "", 'tests' : ""})))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ast.py", line 85, in literal_eval
return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ast.py", line 66, in _convert
    in zip(node.keys, node.values))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ast.py", line 65, in <genexpr>
    return dict((_convert(k), _convert(v)) for k, v
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ast.py", line 84, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x103c50c18>
```

Here is the code that generates the above:

```
test_case_ACT_template = Template('{"__class__":"HttpTestClient","description":"CP Codes","url":"$protocol://$host$path$query","serverip":"$serverip","method":"GET","enabled":true,"headers":[],"tests":[$tests],"purge":false,"procs":[]}')


print(test_case_ACT_template.substitute({'protocol': "",'host': "", 'path' : "", 'query' : "", 'serverip' : "", 'tests' : ""}))

print(ast.literal_eval(test_case_ACT_template.substitute({'protocol': "",'host': "", 'path' : "", 'query' : "", 'serverip' : "", 'tests' : ""})))
```

notice that the first print statement results in the output line that starts with `{"__class__"`

My overall objective is to urlencode my json string but some searching on SO lead me to believe I should first do the `ast.literal_eval` before urlencoding it.

the end goal looks like this:

```
form_data = {'name' : 'CP Code Demo', 'configfilename' : '1-DR4E2_kona-ion.aws-eu-ssl.template_pm-2', 'type' : 'json', 'script' : urlencode(json.load(post_data))}
```

Where `post_data` is a series of Template substitutions.

The original error that lead me to start looking into ast.literal_eval was as follows:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "lexparse.py", line 521, in <module>
form_data = {'name' : 'CP Code Demo', 'configfilename' : '1-DR4E2_kona-ion.aws-eu-ssl.template_pm-2', 'type' : 'json', 'script' : urlencode(post_data)}
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/parse.py", line 862, in urlencode
"or mapping object").with_traceback(tb)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/parse.py", line 854, in urlencode
  raise TypeError
TypeError: not a valid non-string sequence or mapping object
```

Comment: Why in the world are you using `ast.literal_eval()` for this? What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: Updated my question a bit. My end goal is to urlencode the data I'm collecting in the templates shown in the question.

Comment: What library are you using to send that `form_data`? Typically you don't want to do your own escaping/encoding.

Comment: Well, because the site i'm trying to post to requires a client certificate and between python and my Mac OS I'm not able to get the post working with the requests library. So now I'm trying to build a curl command to run on the command line - which is what I would do in Ruby. Hence the self-encoding here. So my goal at the moment (unless there's a better way) is to run subprocess.run().

Comment: If you can't use the requests library, try httplib.

Comment: the real issue with requests or any library is the way Mac handles it's client certificates. I've not found an easy way to pull add the certificates to a request (i've done a LOT of searching) and I'm just working on a proof of concept here. So if I can just run a quick and dirty command-line curl, that would be best for me.

Comment: I'd rather fix the `requests` problem (or use some other library) than trying to pass large strings via CLI. URL encoding will be the least of your worries if you're going down that path.

Comment: well the requests problem is hairier in that i'd run into SSO issues with the API endpoint. Even if I could get the right cert out of my mac keychain and get the request library to send a post properly, it's most likely that I'll run right into the SSO infrastructure that the API endpoint sits behind. With a curl command I can just import my cookies that I pulled from my browser. Even doing that with the requests library was problematic.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be in line with the question, your `Template` seemingly produces a valid JSON so just parse it into a Python `dict` and then give it to the `urllib.parse.urlencode()` to turn it into valid URL params, something like:

```
import json
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from string import Template

your_template = Template('{"__class__":"HttpTestClient","description":"CP Codes",'
                         '"url":"$protocol://$host$path$query","serverip":"$serverip",'
                         '"method":"GET","enabled":true,"headers":[],"tests":[$tests],'
                         '"purge":false,"procs":[]}')

post_data = your_template.substitute({'protocol': "",
                                      'host': "",
                                      'path': "",
                                      'query': "",
                                      'serverip': "",
                                      'tests': ""})

form_data = {'name': 'CP Code Demo',
             'configfilename': '1-DR4E2_kona-ion.aws-eu-ssl.template_pm-2',
             'type': 'json',
             'script': urlencode(json.loads(post_data))}

print(form_data)
```

Then you can feed it to whatever you want. I'd still strongly advise on solving the problem you have with your certificates than just offsetting this to cURL - the issues you might experience when trying to pass large amount of data via CLI can easily overcome the issues you've been experiencing with certificates.

Comment: this was actually really helpful. I know it's a shit way of doing this but baby steps. this is all just to get management on board with the project.

Comment: wait I see another issue here. urlencode actually turns my json object into key value pairs. That's actually not what I want. What I want is to escape the entire json object and post it as is. Going to google that now but if you know how to escape rather than encode let me know.

Comment: If you want to URL escape it, don't parse it as JSON at all - just feed it to `urllib.parse.quote`, e.g.  `'script': urllib.parse.quote(post_data)` . It all depends on what do you want to send `script` value. Technically, you could just send it with no quoting at all - `subprocess.Popen()` ought to escape the special characters so you can pass it to cURL, and cURL should be able to deal with the rest all on its own.

Comment: yes indeed! urllib.parse.quote is exactly what i needed. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's failing is that you aren't capitalizing True and False.

`literal_eval` evaluates an expression as a Python object, not a JSON one, but with constraints. [Per the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html):

> ast.literal_eval(node_or_string) Safely evaluate an expression node or
>   a Unicode or Latin-1 encoded string containing a Python literal or
>   container display. The string or node provided may only consist of the
>   following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists,
>   dicts, booleans, and None.
>
> This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python
>   values from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values
>   oneself. It is not capable of evaluating arbitrarily complex
>   expressions, for example involving operators or indexing.

Notice where it says "booleans and None". In Python, booleans are True and False, and must be capitalized. Your string literal has 'true' and 'false'.

You can take your literal expression and see directly why it doesn't evaluate:

```
>>> x = {"__class__":"HttpTestClient","description":"CP Codes","url":"://","serverip":"","method":"GET","enabled":true,"headers":[],"tests":[],"purge":false,"procs":[]}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'true' is not defined
```

If you're trying to evaluate JSON data, instead of using the AST module, you might consider the [JSON module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).